# помогите добавить список из recyclerview Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

всем привет мне нужно добавить список во фрагмент с названием городов , для этого я создал recyclerView , создал для него адаптер  но у меня инчего не выходит можете помочь пожалуйста по Kotlin.

вот мой код из recycleview adapter

```
class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.Vholder>() {
private var list = arrayListOf<String>()


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Vholder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_linear, parent, false)
    return Vholder(view)
}

fun addlist(item : String){
    list.add(item)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun getItemCount() = list.size

fun update(list: List<String>){
    this.list.clear()
    this.list.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Vholder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(list[position])
}

class Vholder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(data: String) {
        itemView.TVone.text = data
    }
}
```

}

а теперь мне в нижнем фрагменте нужно выявить список с названием городов

```
class AlarmFragment : BaseFragment() {
override fun resID()= R.layout.alarm

private var list = arrayListOf<String>()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    listArr()
}

private fun listArr() {
    val adapter = RecyclerAdapter()
    reclerview.adapter = adapter
    list.add("New Yourk")
    list.add("Vancuover")
    list.add("Berlin")
    list.add("Hamburg")
    list.add("Oslo")
    list.add("Cabo0werde")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали в вашем адаптере метод `addlist()` который должен добавлять элементы по одному. И создали вы его правильно (хотя тут спорный вопрос, почему бы не добавлять сразу весь список, а не по одному. Но это уже детали задач и реализации). И нигде в вашем коде вы его не вызываете.

Второй момент, вы не добавили LayoutManager для вашего recyclerView, а значит ваш RecyclerView не знает как ему рисовать ваши элементы.

Накидаю небольшой пример адаптера:

```
class ImageAdapter :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var items: List<Photo> = emptyList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_image, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        internal fun bind(photo: Photo) {
            with(itemView) {
                // здесь вы уже биндите ваши View как вам нужно
                textView.text = "HelloWorld"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В Activity:

```
private fun initRecycler() {
    imageRecycler.adapter = imageAdapter
    imageRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    imageAdapter.items = photos
}
```